# Remove SPO Site Mailbox using CSOM, REST, anything

Tags: sharepoint-online, client-object-model, site-mailboxes

**How do I remove site mailbox not manually?** 
What I have tried so far:

- Powershell `remove-msoluser` and `remove-mailbox` don't remove the app from SharePoint Online site. If you had a working mailbox and remove it with these cmdlets, you will start getting "Almost ready" and "Setting up" error messages after you click on the mailbox.
- I tried accessing `$context.Web.AllProperties` and modify/deleting/removing these properties:

  ```
  $webProps = $context.Web.AllProperties

  $webProps.Set_Item("ExchangeTeamMailboxSiteCollectionUrl", $NULL)

  $webProps["ExchangeTeamMailboxEmailAddress"]=$NULL

  $webProps.FieldValues.Remove("ExchangeTeamMailboxEmailAddress")

  $context.Web.Update()


  $context.ExecuteQuery()
  $context.Load($webProps)
  $context.ExecuteQuery()
  ```

None of the above had any effect and after the .ExecuteQuery() the properties are still there with the same values as before.

- The site mailbox is not a list and cannot be removed as such from ListCollection of the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the goal only to remove Site Mailbox settings, then you could try the following example:

```
Function Remove-WebProperty([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Web]$Web,[string]$Name)
{
    $webProperties = $Web.AllProperties
    if ($webProperties.FieldValues.ContainsKey($Name) -eq $true) {
        $webProperties[$Name] = $null
    }       
}

$context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($Url)
$context.Credentials = Get-SPOCredentials -UserName $UserName -Password $Password

$context.Load($context.Web.AllProperties)
$context.ExecuteQuery()
$mailboxKeys = @("ExchangeTeamMailboxEmailAddress","ExchangeTeamMailboxSiteCollectionUrl","ExchangeTeamMailboxSiteID","ExchangeTeamMailboxSharePointUrl")
$mailboxKeys | ForEach-Object { Remove-WebProperty $context.Web $_ } 
$context.Web.Update()
$context.ExecuteQuery()

$context.Dispose()
```

Comment: Thank you, but no, the goal is to remove completely the app from SPO site. I just couldn't find a way and properties are sign of desperation. I'll try with some app GUID next.